# How can I print info logs on the console using log4j without using the configuration file in my Java class?

Tags: log4j

Not able to print logs using log4j in my simple java class.

I am just trying to print one liner info log on console using log4j without using the log4j configuration file.

Here is the code snippet

[Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVcP6.png)

I am just trying to get the info logs printed on the console without the help of log4j configuration file .

Comment: Please include your code directly in your question instead of a screenshot ([Code Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting))